# What is easiest way to send message to API from Camunda?

Tags: api, camunda, camunda-modeler

I would like to use easiest way to send API message from Camunda. What is the easiest way? I can't find useful source.

Comment: What kind of (technical) message do you want to send? To which system? Or do you want to send a BPMN message event to Camunda?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to send a BPMN message to the Camunda API.

Via REST see here:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/reference/rest/message/post-message/

Via Java e.g. here:
https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.16/org/camunda/bpm/engine/RuntimeService.html#correlateMessage(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Map)

Answer (score 0):

Use client rest to send the payload (below)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you mean to send http request, the easiest solution is to use `http-conector`. @rob2universe has a good [example](https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda-http-connector-example) about it.